# CSS grid area doesn't work; inspecting shows the areas in the right places, but the images don't follow

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to make a simple grid with only 3 images. I'm trying to do it with grid-template-areas but it's not working at all. When I inspect the page, the areas are properly named and placed, but not at all the right sizes. Also, the images don't line up with the areas

[image: Screenshot of inspect]

Here's my html:

```
<div class="images">
                <a href="#"><div class="image1"><img src="Visuels/Images/CarreRose.jpg"></div></a>
                <a href="#"><div class="image2"><img src="Visuels/Images/TextureRose.jpg"></div></a>
                <a href="#"><div class="image3"><img src="Visuels/Images/FleurRose.jpg"></div></a>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
img{
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.images {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "im3 im1 im1"
                        "im3 im1 im1"
                        "im3 im2 im2";
    margin-right: 20px;
    height:76vh;
    width: 76vh;
}
.image1 {grid-area: im1;}
.image2 {grid-area: im2;}
.image3 {grid-area: im3;}
.image1 img{
    height: 66vh;
    width: 66vh;
}
.image2 img{
    height: 32vh;
    width: 32vh;
}
.image3 img{
    height: 32vh;
    width: 32vh;
}
```

I've only made a CSS grid one time so it's pretty new to me, does anyone know what's happening?

Comment: grid will place the direct children and your element with display grid has 3 children (all anchor elements) and as it's not been told anything about how to place them it just shoves the next one into the next available slot. Your template-areas isn't getting used because the areas are not being linked to these direct children.

Answer (score 0):

This will fix because direct child of grid container are `a` tags.

I made some changes in your code.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  margin:0;
  background-color: bisque;
  font-size: 100px;
}

img{
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.images {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:"im3 im1 im1"
                      "im3 im1 im1"
                      "im3 im2 im2";
  /* margin-right: 20px; */
  height:76vh;
  width: 76vh;
}
a:nth-child(1) {grid-area: im1;}
a:nth-child(2) {grid-area: im2;}
a:nth-child(3) {grid-area: im3;}
```

```html
<div class="images">
      <a href="#"
        ><div class="image1">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x400" /></div
      ></a>
      <a href="#"
        ><div class="image2">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x400" /></div
      ></a>
      <a href="#"
        ><div class="image3">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x1200" /></div
      ></a>
</div>
```